# add an explicite field in django admin page for a self recursive model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, admin

My **admin.py**:

```
@admin.register(Group)
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'group_id',
        'group_name',
        'groupParent_id',
    )
    list_filter = (
        'group_name',
    )
```

My **models.py**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    groupParent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,    related_name='Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I would like to see in admin django page for `Group` a field in which I have tuhe name of the group `Parent` (`ForeginKey`).

Comment: sorry for poor doc as i don t know why i add an issue with stackoverflow to edit my code

Comment: I want to have in django admin page of Group model , a field that present parent name (not the id of the parent). thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@admin.register(Group)
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'group_id',
        'group_name',
        'groupParent_id__group_name',
    )

    list_filter = (
        'group_name',
    )
```